# form onsubmit delaying window.open not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to figure this out for past few hours, I have form and when users will submit it,

new window popup will occur, however I want it delayed slightly, setting setTimeout did not work and I have no idea why.

example:

```
<form method="post" target="print_popup" action="https://example.com" onsubmit="window.open('about:blank','print_popup','width=1000,height=800');">
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="foobar">
<input id="1" type="submit" value="Submit request">
```

Comment: That is because you did not prevent the default submit event from firing in the `onsubmit` callback, so the user is redirected to the form's action immediately when they submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Think you will need to set the `target` attribute of the form to `_blank` to allow for opening a new context: [image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

I would also check chrome/your choice of browser isn't blocking your popup

Comment: Opening the window and doing POST request is not the problem, what I wanted is to delay the window.open for 1-3 seconds. Im on Chrome

Comment: if you move the onsubmit callback into a separate method it might be easier to debug why it isn't working. setTimeout will be the correct method for waiting a moment of time before performing an action.

Comment: could you possibly share example code which would work? Im still trying to understand this.